# SQL Server Abrir archivo dtsx

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

Al dar doble clic a un archivo dtsx me lo muestra de la siguiente forma (imagen), tenia instalado SQL Server 2008 R2

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al instalar SQL Server 2019 Developer al dar doble clic al archivo dtsx me pide buscar o seleccionar el programa para abrirlo (no lo abre como la imagen anterior), ya instale el Integration Services y sigue el mismo mensaje

Me estará haciendo falta algo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos y en espera de su amable ayuda.

---

Gracias por tu pronta respuesta, yo lo ejecuto el archivo dtsx desde un procedimiento almacenado, pero no lo ejecuta desde que migre a SQL Server 2019. Con SQL Server 2008 lo ejecuta sin problemas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

DOs cosas:

- Ese archivo contiene un package, por lo que debes tener instalado [SQL server integration services projects](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SSIS.SqlServerIntegrationServicesProjects).
- Como es un package y no un proyecto, debes abrir el .proj correspondiente (o crear el proyecto) y desde el solutions explorer, abres el dtsx.

Answer (score 0):

Básicamente debes tener el projecto para editar ese .dtsx
es como tener el ejecutable pero no el código.
En tu captura de pantalla solo estás viendo la ejecución de ese package.

Comment: Ricardo Diaz exactamente ese es el punto, el Dtsx lo contrui pero con SQL 2008 y bien el archivo es un ejecutable. Al instalar SQL 2019 el Dtsx al dar doble clic como es ejecutable no se muestra me pide que seleccione el programa con el que lo quiero abrir. Esa es la pregunta, que me hace falta para ejecutarlo como un ejecutable propiamente.